# GCM push notification server side response for Android using C#?

Tags: android

I'm implementing GCM push notification server side  for Android using C#:
The problem is that the notification has not been received to the device, and i dont know where is the problem, is it from the server or from application?
Here's the server side response " id=0:1373508394613753%f73a6d8d66d6cf16", i dont know does this response mean?
So anyone can tell me does this response mean that the notification is sent but there is a problem in the device or vice versa?

Here's Server Side Code:

```
public string SendAndroidPushNotification(string RegistrationID, string message)
        {

            string GoogleAppID = "AIzaSyAq8TKNRJpp18B9Xvc6PcM4ji8igU";          
            var SENDER_ID = "5525610314545";
            var value = message;
            WebRequest tRequest;
            tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
            tRequest.Method = "post";
            tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

            tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

            string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + RegistrationID + "";
            //Console.WriteLine(postData);
            Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
            tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

            Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
            dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
            dataStream.Close();

            WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

            dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

            StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

            String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

            HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)tResponse;
            string statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();

            tReader.Close();
            dataStream.Close();
            tResponse.Close();
            return sResponseFromServer;
        }
```

Here's the reference to the Andriod Application Code:

[Push Notification receiver is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625499/push-notification-receiver-is-not-working)

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error and fixed it with the following steps:

1. JSON:
   I changed my server code (send push to gcm) to json format. After that we got a success-result. See: [stackoverflow sample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18508674/gcm-using-json-to-send-to-multiple-registrationids-no-notification-arrives)
2. DEVICE:
   Check the methods in your client code. In our case, the message was received by the device but not displayed (we used the google sample code - and it didn't work).

Also have a look a this one: [an other stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13929790/ive-got-this-response-from-the-gcm-server-success1-but-the-notification-no)

Feel free to responde...

Answer (score 0):

You need to include RegistrationID in your push notification at server side.