# GCM Using JSON to send to multiple RegistrationIDs : No notification arrives

Tags: c#, android, json, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using Android Google Cloud Messaging to send notifications to a device, with c#.net. I got the API Key, RegistrationID and senderID ( Well first method worked no there's nothing wrong with the configuration of GCM).

Here's the first method where I want to send the message to just 1 registrationID(check postData, i'm not using Json):

```c#
    public void SendPushNotification(string regID, string message)
 {


     {
         string GoogleAppID = "APIKey";
         var SENDER_ID = "SenderID";
         var value = message;
         WebRequest tRequest;
         tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
         tRequest.Method = "post";
         tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
         tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

         tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

         string postData = "collapse_key=score_update&time_to_live=108&delay_while_idle=1&data.message=" + value + "&data.time=" + System.DateTime.Now.ToString() + "&registration_id=" + regID + "";
         Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
         tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

         Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
         dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
         dataStream.Close();

         WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

         dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

         StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

         String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

         HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)tResponse;
         string statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();

         tReader.Close();
         dataStream.Close();
         tResponse.Close();
     }
        catch {
            throw new WebFaultException<string>("Error", HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
        }
```

So when calling it, the device successfully receives the message.

Here's my second method, where I use Json format to send to multiple IDs:
(Note that the procedure doesn't take registrationID as a parameter because I added it to the list i declared in the code)

```c#
    public void SendPushNotification(string message)
 {

     string stringregIds = null;
     List<string> regIDs = new List<string>();
     //Here I add the registrationID that I used in Method #1 to regIDs
     //Then I use 
     stringregIds = string.Join("\",\"", regIDs);
     //To Join the values (if ever there are more than 1) with quotes and commas for the Json format below



     try
     {
         string GoogleAppID = "APIKey";
         var SENDER_ID = "SenderID";
         var value = message;
         WebRequest tRequest;
         tRequest = WebRequest.Create("https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
         tRequest.Method = "post";
         tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
         tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Authorization: key={0}", GoogleAppID));

         tRequest.Headers.Add(string.Format("Sender: id={0}", SENDER_ID));

         string postData = "{\"collapse_key\":\"score_update\",\"time_to_live\":108,\"delay_while_idle\":true,\"data\": { \"message\" : "+"\""+value+"\",\"time\": "+"\""+System.DateTime.Now.ToString()+"\"},\"registration_ids\":[\""+stringregIds+"\"]}";

         Byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
         tRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

         Stream dataStream = tRequest.GetRequestStream();
         dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
         dataStream.Close();

         WebResponse tResponse = tRequest.GetResponse();

         dataStream = tResponse.GetResponseStream();

         StreamReader tReader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

         String sResponseFromServer = tReader.ReadToEnd();

         HttpWebResponse httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)tResponse;
         string statusCode = httpResponse.StatusCode.ToString();

         tReader.Close();
         dataStream.Close();
         tResponse.Close();
     }
        catch {
            throw new WebFaultException<string>("Error", HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable);
        }
```

The Method doesn't give any errors or anything but the notification doesn't arrive in the device. (I console.writelined postData and it's the same format of http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html
So I don't really know what to fix, it would be really easier to send notifications to users at the same time not just send 1 to each User every X seconds.

Thanks.

Comment: `tRequest.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";` in the "second method" ... and you are using JSON ... read doc again ...

Comment: Oh wow ,i'm gonna try it now. Thanks !

Comment: It worked , i'm so silly. Thanks again Selvin

Answer (score 2):

Changing

```
Request.ContentType = " application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
```

to

```
Request.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Does answer the question.

He is providing JSON data where he has explicitly implied quite the opposite.

The HTTP header must contain the following headers:

> Content-Type: application/json for JSON;
>   application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8 for plain text.

See: https://developer.android.com/google/gcm/http.html

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Request.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Comment: Some commentary other than a blunt (though accurate) answer would help the author

Answer (score -5):

Replace this line:

```
Request.ContentType = "application/json";
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: @ScottThompson Sure it does. Just needs a quit edit.

Comment: @Keyner, could you elaborate a bit on your answer?