# GCM push notifications | Inconsistent retrieval, unwanted delays, and empty bundle

Tags: java, android, push-notification, google-api, google-cloud-messaging

I am integrating push notifications in my app for tickles and basic messaging. The idea is they will never be sent from the server (Cloud to device) but rather from a device (device to device). The third server I am using is [Firebase](http://firebase.com).

I can register with GCM just fine. But, when I send a message 50% of the time I never see it. When I do, it takes over 10 minutes to get it, and the bundle is always empty.  Here is my code:

To register, I call this from my Application.java

```
GcmRegister gcmRegister = new GcmRegister(this);
gcmRegister.register();
```

To send a post, I do this asynchronously:

```
 try {
       Bundle b = new Bundle()
       b.putString("title", title);
       b.putString("message", message);
       ///apikey is the id i get from registering with GCM
       gcm.send(apiKey + "@gcm.googleapis.com", String.valueOf(new AtomicInteger().incrementAndGet()), b);

  } catch (IOException e) 
       log.e(e.getMessage());
       e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<permission android:name="com.super.secret.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.super.secret.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />

<application
     ....
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version" android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

   <service android:name="com.super.secret.core.gcm.GcmIntentService"/>

   <receiver
        android:name="com.super.secret.core.gcm.GcmReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.gcm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.super.secret" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
     ....
</application>
```

**GCMRegister.java** seems to work right

```
public class GcmRegister {

    private static String SENDER_ID;
    private Context mContext;
    private String mDeviceId;
    private String mAccountName;
    private String mRegistrationId;

    private final UserManager mUserManager = UserManager.getInstance();
    private GoogleCloudMessaging gcm;
    private Prefs mPrefs;

    public GcmRegister(Context context) {
        this.mContext = context;
        mPrefs = new Prefs(mContext);
        gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mContext);

       initStrings();
    }

    public void register() {
       if (checkPlayServices()) {
           if (getRegistrationId().isEmpty()) {
                registerWithGcm();
           } else {
               save();
           }

       } else {
           Log.i(TAG, "No valid Google Play Services APK found.");
       }
    }

    private void initStrings() {
        SENDER_ID = mContext.getString(R.string.gcm_project_number);
        mAccountName = mPrefs.getAccountName();
        mDeviceId = Settings.Secure.getString(mContext.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
     }

     private void registerWithGcm() {
         new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>() {
           @Override
           protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
               try {
                   if (gcm == null) {
                      gcm = GoogleCloudMessaging.getInstance(mContext);
                   }
                  Log.i(TAG, "SenderId: " + SENDER_ID);
                  mRegistrationId = gcm.register(SENDER_ID);
                  Log.i(TAG, "Device registered, registration ID=" + mRegistrationId);

                  save();

               } catch (IOException ex) {
                   log.e("Error :" + ex.getMessage());
                   ex.printStackTrace();

              }
              return null;
           }
       }.execute();
    }

    private void save() {
        // Persist the regID - no need to register again.
       int appVersion = getAppVersion();
       Log.i(TAG, "Saving regId on app version " + appVersion);
       mPrefs.setGcmAuthId(mRegistrationId);
       mPrefs.setAppVersion(appVersion);

       //save to Firebase
       ....
    }

    private String getRegistrationId() {
        String registrationId = mPrefs.getGcmAuthId();
        if (registrationId.isEmpty()) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Registration not found.");
            return "";
        }
        // Check if app was updated; if so, it must clear the registration ID
        // since the existing regID is not guaranteed to work with the new
        // app version.
       int registeredVersion = mPrefs.getAppVersion();
       int currentVersion = getAppVersion();
       if (registeredVersion != currentVersion) {
           log.i("App version changed.");
           mPrefs.setGcmAuthId("");
           return "";
       }
       return registrationId;
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(mContext);
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
               Log.i(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            }
           return false;
       }
       return true;
    }

    private int getAppVersion() {
       try {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = mContext.getPackageManager()
                   .getPackageInfo(mContext.getPackageName(), 0);
            return packageInfo.versionCode;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            // should never happen
            throw new RuntimeException("Could not get package name: " + e);
       }
    }
}
```

**BroadcastReceiver.java**

```
 public class GcmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
       Log.i(TAG, "Message received!!!");
       // Explicitly specify that GcmIntentService will handle the intent.
       ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            GcmIntentService.class.getName());
      // Start the service, keeping the device awake while it is launching.
      startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
      setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);
   }
}
```

**GcmIntentService.java**

```
 public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {

     public GcmIntentService() {
        super("GcmIntentService");
     }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Intent Service Called");
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        String title = extras.getString("title");
        String message = extras.getString("message");

        NotificationClient noteClient = new NotificationClient(this);
        noteClient.showNotification(title, message);
        // Release the wake lock provided by the WakefulBroadcastReceiver.
        GcmReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
    }
}
```

---

**NOTE:** A notification is shown, but with no title and no message. I have briefly tried to break on the broadcast receiver to see what the bundle actually contains, but I cant be sure when I will receive the message. So I have yet to successfully step through it.

Comment: are you using the collapse_key or not?

Comment: whats your payload? the limit is 4kb

Comment: @KayAnn I only sent a message containing "test"

Comment: ok try this one thing.. put message_type in your Broadcast receiver. Just so if the message has collapsed you can get it when you sync again. Might just work. Here's the docs on it: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/gcm/GoogleCloudMessaging.html#getMessageType(android.content.Intent)

Comment: It will be a few days before I can test it. When I do I will let you know.